# Spring Boot jupiter annotation custom extension configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, spring-annotations, junit-jupiter

I have configured a custom annotation:

```
@Target(allowedTargets = [AnnotationTarget.TYPE, AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS, AnnotationTarget.CLASS])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(value = [SpringExtension::class, BuilderTestExtension::class])
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestConfig::class])
@SpringBootTest
annotation class BuilderTest
```

and also I have configured the TestConfig:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = ["com.example.api.base.builder"]
)
class TestConfig
```

the BuilderHelper is defined as such where ResponseBuilder class is defined in `com.example.api.base.builder` package:

```
@Service
class BuilderHelper(@Autowired var responseBuilder: ResponseBuilder)
```

everything works fine so far. When I try though to create another annotation for serialization tests such as:

```
@Target(allowedTargets = [AnnotationTarget.TYPE, AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS, AnnotationTarget.CLASS])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(value = [SpringExtension::class, SerializationTestExtension::class])
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [SerializationConfig::class])
@SpringBootTest
annotation class SerializationTest
```

Serialization config file is defined:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackageClasses = [ObjectMapper::class]
)
class SerializationConfig
```

and SerializationHelper where `ObjectMapper` class is an external library with package name `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`:

```
@Service
class SerializationHelper(@Autowired var objectMapper: ObjectMapper)
```

Now my error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

which I assume is because of the configuration. Somehow I want to make those 2 annotations or extensions independent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is a little bit overcomplicated.

You can make use of `@TestConfiguration` annotation in order to completely isolate your testContext from applicationContext.

Reference: [TestConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html)

What I suggest that you can do is this:

Modify your `@BuilderTest` annotation as such:

```
@Target(allowedTargets = [AnnotationTarget.TYPE, AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS, AnnotationTarget.CLASS])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Import(TestConfig::class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
annotation class BuilderTest
```

as you can see the `@SpringBootTest` annotation is missing so that you can isolate the context for test classes specifically. Furthermore you no longer need `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.

Modify your TestConfig as such:

```
@TestConfiguration
class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    fun responseBuilder(): ResponseBuilder {
        // return the instance of ResponseBuilder class here
    }
}
```

Then in your test class you can simply do this:

```
@BuilderTest
class ResponseBuilderTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var responseBuilder: ResponseBuilder

    @Test
    fun testResponseBuilder() {
        //  your test logic goes here
    }
}
```

you can follow this procedure and do the same for `@SerializationTest` by creating an additional Configuration class using the `@TestConfiguration` annotation and providing the instance for `ObjectMapper`.